# Regex - Match 3-digit numbers

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex-expression for a code editor (Brackets) to find 3-digit numbers in the following format

```
129 (3-digit WITHOUT DOT)
107.23 (3-digit DOT 2-digit)
```

BUT NOT

```
117.234 (3-digit DOT 3-digit or more)
X306 (Character before number)
```

I've tried this: `[0-9]{3,3}[.][0-9]{0,2}|\b\d{3,3}\b`

But it does also match `117.234 / 105.123432` partly....

```
X306
50.17080
8.69507,
50.178075,
50.050512
117.234
49.172
129
105.123432
107.23
```

Comment: Maybe `\b(?<!\d\.)(?:[0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{1,2}|\d{3})\b(?!\.\d)`? See https://regex101.com/r/HiZWNW/1

Comment: Oh yes! Perfect! Thank you so much! I should have asked before spending half of the day to find it out myself ;-)

Comment: Ok, so `\b(?<!\d\.)\d{3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?\b(?!\.\d)` will also work, it is a bit more efficient and shorter.

Comment: `\b(?<![\d.])\d{3}(?:\.\d{2})?(?![\d.])`

Answer (score 5):

You may use

```
\b(?<!\d\.)\d{3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?\b(?!\.\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HiZWNW/2).

**Details**

- `\b(?<!\d\.)` - a word boundary not preceded with a digit and a dot
- `\d{3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - 3 digits followed with an optional sequence of `.` and 1 or 2 digits
- `\b(?!\.\d)` - a word boundary not followed with a dot and a digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can minimalize your regex using the below which covers all your cases.
Result is a quicker regex.

`\b(?<!\.)\d{3}(?:\.\d{2})?\b(?!\.)`

https://regex101.com/r/UjdTAi/1

```
 \b 
 (?<! \. )
 \d{3} 
 (?:
      \. \d{2} 
 )?
 \b   
 (?! \. )
```

Benchmark

```
Regex1:   \b(?<!\.)\d{3}(?:\.\d{2})?\b(?!\.)
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    1.18 s,   1175.88 ms,   1175882 µs
Matches per sec:   85,042


Regex2:   \b(?<!\d\.)\d{3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?\b(?!\.\d)
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    1.31 s,   1307.20 ms,   1307199 µs
Matches per sec:   76,499
```

Comment: Except the accepted answer will accept '123.4' but yours will not. Based on what the OP tried as a solution, it appears that yours should.